# Use valueChangeListener inside selectOneMenu component of IceFaces

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I have two dropdowns `selectOneMenu` in my JSF / IceFaces page, as per my requirement I want to render value inside another dropdown based on selection of first dropdown.

I have written below piece of code for that

```
<ice:outputText value="Category *" id="category" />
    <ice:selectOneMenu id="category"
                       value="#{createItem.categoryId}"
                       tabindex="4"
                       valueChangeListener="#{createItem.searchSubCategory}"
                       partialSubmit="true">

        <f:selectItems value="#{createItem.categoryList}" />
    </ice:selectOneMenu>                

    <ice:outputText value="Sub Category *" id="subcategory" />

    <ice:selectOneMenu id="subcategory"
        value="#{createItem.subCategoryId}" tabindex="5" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{createItem.subCategoryList}" />
    </ice:selectOneMenu>
```

```
public void searchSubCategory(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    try {

        subCategoryList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        subCategoryList.add(new SelectItem(0,"-- Select --"));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" searchSubCategory exception  ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        showMessageDialog(ProjectConstants.ERROR, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But after calling `searchSubCategory` method two dropdowns are generated one with blank value another with value `-- Select --`

Comment: I got the problem it was due to id conflict. I have changed value of id and it is working fine

Comment: Great that you solved your problem. It would be helpful for everybody if you put your resolution into an [answer to your own question and accept it by yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).